# Umbraco 4.7: cmsDocument corrupted, how to delete the Document/Node?

Tags: umbraco

I have a really weird issue on a particular node (nodeId 3095) in Umbraco 4.7:

- In `cmsDocument`, there is 1 published row and **0 newest** row.
- In the CMS (ie. website.com/umbraco/) the node doesn't appear anywhere.
- In umbraco.config, the node always appears (I tried republishing the parent node & republish all)
- When I do this:
  `UPDATE cmsDocument SET newest=1 WHERE nodeId=3095 AND published=1`

  the node will appear in the CMS under Contents,
  but when clicked, it gives an error:

> No Document exists with Version 'bbbbb872-b97b-4db5-9304-a3489ddd5540'

- This query returns nothing:
  `SELECT * FROM cmsDocument WHERE versionId='bbbbb872-b97b-4db5-9304-a3489ddd5540'`

**Updated question:**
How do you safely delete a Document from the database? (because you can't delete it from the CMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried deleting that version (only 1 row) from cmsContentVersion and apparently it works.

What I did wrong was I tried setting newest manually. Apparently you shouldn't do that manually.

Similar instruction: http://www.spyriadis.net/2011/08/umbraco-fix-no-document-exists-with-version/